# Second Page Session Variable Not Showing Session Variable From First Page

Tags: php, html

So, I created a session_start and created two html input text boxes on the first page. I thought I correctly coded the if statements in the primary PHP block but alas, am unable to use the submitted values on the secondary page. I've made small alternations on both pages, nothing major, but cannot get the second page to show these session variables. What am I missing here?

```html
   //FIRST Page
   
   <!DOCTYPE>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>  
      <title>Product Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"
  </head>
     <body>
     <form method=“post” action="orderPage.php">
     <p>Enter the number of items you would like to order in each respective text box</p>
       <label>Apples <input name="Apples" /></label>
    <br>
          <label>Bananas <input name=“Bananas” /></label>
           <input type="submit" value="Checkout"></form>

     <?php

     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['Apples'])) {
        $Apples = 0;
        $_SESSION['Apples'] = $Apples;
    } else {
        $Apples = $_POST['Apples'];
        $_SESSION['Apples'] = $Apples;
    }

    if (empty($_POST['Bananas'])) {
        $Bananas = 0;
        $_SESSION['Bananas'] = $Bananas;
    } else {
        $Bananas = $_POST['Bananas'];
        $_SESSION['Bananas'] = $Bananas;
    }?>
</body>
</html>


//Second Page

<!DOCTYPE>
<?php  
session_start();?>
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Product Page</title>  
<meta charset="UTF-8"
</head> <body> <h3>Order Confirmation Page</h3>
<?php  
echo "Apples : " . $_SESSION['Apples'] . "<br>";echo "Bananas : " . $_SESSION['Bananas'] . "<br>";?>
<input type="submit" method="post" value="Checkout">  

<?php  
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){echo "Your order has been placed.";session_destroy();}?>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: The reason that the session variables aren't being set is that when you open first page there is no submit therefore these variable are not set. Move the isset($_POST... to the second page.

Answer (score 0):

You Have some mistakes, there are, } missing end of the page 1 submit form, and and not using PHP function top of the page. So I have tested and following code will helps you.

page 1

```
session_start();
$Apples = 0;
$Bananas = 0;

if (isset($_POST)) {
 if (empty($_POST['Apples'])) {
    $_SESSION['Apples'] = $Apples;
 } else {
    $Apples = $_POST['Apples'];
    $_SESSION['Apples'] = $Apples;
 }

 if (empty($_POST['Bananas'])) {
    $_SESSION['Bananas'] = $Bananas;
 } else {
    $Bananas = $_POST['Bananas'];
    $_SESSION['Bananas'] = $Bananas;
}

//echo json_encode($_SESSION);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="orderPage.php" method="post">
   Apples: <input type="text" name="Apples"><br>
   Bananas: <input type="text" name="Bananas"><br>
   <input type="submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

And Your 2nd page

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST)) {
session_destroy();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Product Page</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head> <body> <h3>Order Confirmation Page</h3>
<?php
 echo "Apples : " . $_SESSION['Apples'] . "<br>";echo "Bananas : " . $_SESSION['Bananas'] . "<br>";?>
<form class="" action="" method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="Checkout">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Think this will help you.